# How do I allow dividing by zero?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a lillte C# application that will calcualte how much school work you've done.

```
     calc1 = totalIp / totalPidl;
        percentageBox.Text = percbox;
        percbox = calc1.ToString();
```

the error happens at calc1 = totalip / totalPidl;
there are no typos or anything else.
how can i allow dividing by zero?

Thanks.

Comment: What result do you expect while dividing by zero?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: You need to check if `totalPidl` is zero BEFORE doing the division - then if it is zero put a special message into the text box (e.g. "overflow") rather than the result of the calculation. I recommend NOT changing the displayed result to zero as per some of the other answers here...

Comment: There will never be "divide by zero" in a right way, try `totalIp / (totalPidl == 0 ? 1 : totalPidl);` or the other suggestions based on whether you want the whole thing to be 0 or just the nominator.

Comment: It is not a good idea to allow division by zero.

Comment: To make this easy for you: https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/05/07/why-cant-you-divide-by-zero/

Answer (score 3):

That's mathematically impossible.

Prevent division by zero by code:

```
if(totalPidl == 0.0)
{
  percentageBox.Text = "???";
}
else
{   
  calc1 = totalIp / totalPidl;
  percentageBox.Text = calc1.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to allow division by zero. What value do you want? does it make sense? It is better to do something like this:

```
calc1 = totalPidl != 0 ? totalIp / totalPidl : 0; // I assume you want the result to be 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you allow a division by zero? Give a try catch block with specified output to display "No work done" if the division by zero is going to happen.
[Read this for better understanding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by zero does not give a valid mathematical result. To avoid the exception you can use a ternary operator that will return 0 when *totalPidl* is 0:

```
calc1 = totalPidl != 0 ? totalIp / totalPidl : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand you want to have `0` result if you have `0` denominator. So you can use ternary `if` operator:

```
calc1 = totalPidl == 0 ? 0: totalIp / totalPidl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid DivideByZeroException. You can ignore it by catching the exception or have a condition and check for 0 before  doing the calculation

```
calc1 = 0;
try
{
   calc1 = totalIp / totalPidl;
}
finally
{
    percentageBox.Text = percbox;
    percbox = calc1.ToString();
}
```

Or

```
if(totalIp != 0)
{
   calc1 = totalIp / totalPidl;
}
percentageBox.Text = percbox;
percbox = calc1.ToString();
```